# Rewind offset for Spring Integration Kafka consumer

Tags: spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka

Is there a way to rewind the offset of the Kafka consumer using `spring-integration-kafka`? I want something like the `--from-beginning` option that can be used with kafka console consumer script.

My consumer configuration looks like this:

```
<bean id="consumerProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="auto.offset.reset">smallest</prop>
            <prop key="socket.receive.buffer.bytes">10485760</prop> <!-- 10M -->
            <prop key="fetch.message.max.bytes">5242880</prop>
            <prop key="auto.commit.interval.ms">1000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [constructor that takes `TopicPartitionInitialOffset`s](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafkamessagelistenercontainer).

Comment: Problem is I'm not using a `message-driven-channel-adapter`. I'm actually polling kafka using `inbound-channel-adapter`. Would this still work?

Comment: Oh, you are using the old 1.x version - that adapter uses the high-level 0.8 consumer and doesn't provide offset management - see [the readme](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/tree/1.3.x#inbound-channel-adapter).

Comment: It's been ages, but I finally updated and it works like a charm.